# Good, satisfied and bad numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Set of natural numbers is divided in to the following three set

1) Good numbers

2) Satisfied numbers

3) Bad numbers

The conditions given are :

(I)   Y is a function on X and X is either $0$ or $2^X$

(II)  (Y = X) if and only if either  N is a Good number or N is a Satisfied number

(III)  (Y = $0$) if and only if   N is a Satisfied number

Question is

Whether

(Y =$2^X$) if and only if N is a Good number

is valid or not ?

*My approach:*

P : N is a Good number

Q : N is a satisfied number

R : Y =$0$

S : Y =$2^X$

T : Y=X

From above I can get

(Y=X) $\iff$ $((Y=2^X) \oplus (Y=$0$))$ $\cdots$ from(I)

(Y=X) $\iff$ ( P $\oplus$ Q )  $\cdots$ from(II)

$((Y=0) \oplus (Y=2^X))$ $\iff$ ( P $\oplus$ Q ) $\cdots$ from above two

$(Y=0) \iff Q$ $\cdots $ from(III)

$(Y=2^X) \iff P$ $\cdots$ from above two

I am believing that my approach is correct. But I did analysis considering only Good numbers and Satisfied numbers. So I am thinking that it is closed world result and is true for only Good numbers and Satisfied numbers and there may exist bad numbers such that $Y=2^X$

My doubt is whether the result that

Y=$0$ if and only if N is a Good number

Is correct for all natural numbers or for all natural numbers except Bad numbers .

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: aren't you missing some assumption about $N$ in (I) (II) or (III) ?

Comment: Not missed any assumption .

Comment: where do you define N ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(Y=0)\oplus(Y=2^X)$ is not equivalent to $Y=X$, so the argument is not correct: it’s possible that $Y=0$ and $X=2^X$, in which case $(Y=0)\oplus(Y=2^X)$ is true and $Y=X$ is false. (Note that $X=2^X$ makes little sense, but that’s the way you’ve described the problem.) In fact the result is false. One way to discover this is to try to prove it.

Suppose that $N$ is Good. Then $Y=X$ by (II), and $Y\ne 0$ by (III), so $X\ne 0$, and therefore $X=2^X$ by (I). Since $Y=X$, this implies that $Y=2^X$. So far the proof works just fine.

Now suppose that $N$ is not Good; then either $N$ is Satisfied, or $N$ is Bad. If $N$ is Satisfied, then $Y=0$ by (III), so $Y\ne 2^X$. Here again there is no problem.

If $N$ is Bad, then $Y\ne 0$ by (III). I interpret (I) to mean that $Y$ has the same possible values as $X$, so if $Y\ne 0$, then $Y=2^X$. This shows that the result is false: we’ve actually proved that $Y=2^X$ if and only if $N$ is not Satisfied, i.e., if and only if $N$ is either Good or Bad.

It **is** true that $X=2^X$ if and only if $N$ is Good. If $N$ is Good, we already showed that $Y=2^X$, and from (II) we know that $Y=X$, so $X=2^X$. If $N$ is Satisfied, we already showed that $Y=0$, and from (II) we know that $Y=X$, so $X=0$, and therefore $X\ne 2^X$. Finally, if $N$ is Bad, we just showed that $Y=2^X$, and (II) implies that $Y\ne X$, so $X\ne 2^X$. Thus, $X=2^X$ if and only if $N$ is Good.

Comment: If X is a function that takes two values $o,2^X$ instead of 1 i replaced $2^x$ . Then also ur answer holds ?

Comment: @hanu: I don’t understand the question. If $X$ is a Boolean variable, it takes the values $0$ and $1$.

Comment: There Y may be the integer but X is only the boolean variable . How we can say that (Y = 0) $\oplus$  (Y=1) is a fact ?

Comment: Y becomes boolean variable iff N belongs to either Good or satisfied number . Otherwise it neednot be a boolean variable.

Comment: @hanu: The statement $Y=X$ makes sense if and only if $Y$ is a Boolean variable. If it were a variable of some other type, it would take values in a different set from $X$. And the first thing that I’d do, if I were you, is check the statement of the problem: I suspect that the question is about whether $X=1$ iff $N$ is Good.

Comment: @Brain M.scott I am sorry that is the actual one ( edited question ) . :(

Comment: @hanu: It really is with $X=1$? That’s okay; I covered that in the last paragraph of my answer. You can turn the argument into formal symbols, if you’re required to do so, but I think that it’s more understandable in words, so I’ll leave it as I wrote it, at least for now.